# Scripting LMMS from Python

Tags: python, audio-player, lmms

Recently I [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267628/scripting-fruityloops-or-propellerheads-reason-from-vb-or-python) about scripting FruityLoops or Reason from Python, which didn't turn up much.

Today I found [LMMS](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/), a free-software FruityLoops clone. So, similarly. Has anyone tried scripting this from Python (or similar)? Is there an API or wrapper for accessing its resources from outside?

If not, what would be the right approach to try writing one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you can [write plugins](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php?title=Plugin_development_tutorial) for LMMS using C++. By [embedding Python in the C++ plugin](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/ext/embedding.html) you can effectively script the program in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://www.csounds.com/ for an approach to scripting music synth programs in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect pretty much everything in LMMS to a MIDI input. Try that?